# How do I get the entered value of activeTextField in Yii?

Tags: yii

the code below works without creating a submit button but I want to assign 'id' with newly entered value in the textfield.  How do I get it?

```
<?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'id',array(
    'submit' => array('item/view'),
    'id' => 1, // this one works when you press enter at the textField; however, I
               // want to assign here the current value of textfield
)); ?>
```

TIA

What I am trying to achieve here is a record/model navigator like record navigation control in M$ Access with firstRecord, prevRecord, nextRecord, lastRecord links. I have implemented those four links easily.  The current record element, the code above should display the current record id but it should also enable the user to change its value so that it will navigate to Model 'id' of choice.

Comment: You want the model's value of that field, or do you want to change the value of the id to the textfield's value at submission?

Comment: what you are trying to achieve is very strange... i think you should try a different approach for whatever you are trying to do. i am sure there is a much better way to do it

Comment: perhaps you didn't realize that 'id' was reserved for creating a fixed, unique identifier for each control in a web page. It's not for holding the value of say a user ID entered into a text field. That should be assigned to the 'data' property which is then returned to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want, though it's not what you asked for:

```
<?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'id',array(
    'submit' => array('item/view'),
    'id' => 'control_id', 
    'data'=> array('user_id'=> 'js:$("#control_id'.$instanceName.'").val()'),
)); ?>
```

I would be surprised if Yii even allows you to dynamically assign a user-entered value to the the control id, like you ask. That would open a security hole, allowing the user to trigger any control in that view (even hidden form fields) if he could guess the right id.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  With barely 1 month experience in PHP & Yii, I admit I still do noobish things.  Could somebody help me out on how to create model navigator securely?

Comment: Do all the model navigation within the controller, just do a validation and escape on any text submitted by the user before using it to then select and CRUD a model. I'm not familiar with a MS model navigator, but I think the standard Gii CRUD would accomplish most everything "model navigation" means to me -- Create, Update, & Delete model records. This is the very first step in the Yii tutorial: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app#implementing-crud-operations

Comment: And if you upvote responses to your question, you may motivate others  (that are familiar with Microsoft Access model navigators) to provide even better answers. That's how this site ranks questions and answers and users.